# How to prove elegantly this inequality?

Tags: inequality

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ three reals greater than or equal to 1. Put $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+bc+ca=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$. Show that
$$w-\frac{1}{w}\ge\frac{w^3}{v^2}-\frac{1}{u}$$

I am able to prove it by assuming without loss of generality that $c\ge b\ge a$ and posing $b=a+u$ and $c=a+u+v$ for $u,v\ge0$. The problem here is that when plug  this two expression and develop, I get a huge polynomial of $a$ whose coefficients are all positive. I am wondering if there a possibility to obtain a more elegant solution.

Comment: (1) Please post your solution.  (2)  Please specify what you are looking for without using vague terms like "more elegant", i.e.  Please operationalize "more elegant."

Comment: Perhaps you could use AM-GM to find the relations of $u, v, w$ and then work with those.

Comment: Thank you @amWhy for your reply. I gave the methodology of my solution where I used Maple to get the final (very huge) expression, I only checked that all the coefficients are positive.

Comment: probable typo, should be $ab+bc+ca = 3 v^2$  for proper scaling

Comment: Indeed, thank you @WillJagy !

Comment: Are you sure about your solution?  How did you use the fact that $ a \geq 1$? Note that this isn't true with $ a \rightarrow 0$.If all that you had are positive coefficients, then this would also hold for $ a > 0$.

Comment: I made first a change of variable $a\to a-1$, $b\to b-1$ and $c\to c-1$. That is the reason why the final polynomial of a is so huge.

Comment: Please add full details instead of requiring us to ask questions in order to understand what's going on in your head. Snippits of what you did are helpful, even if the huge polynomial is too huge to reproduce.

Comment: The problem is also stated as follows: Let $a, b, c\ge 1$. Prove that $\sqrt[3]{abc} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}
\ge \frac{3abc}{ab+bc+ca} - \frac{3}{a+b+c}$.
As OP said, the Buffalo Way (BW) works.

Comment: Here's another way to state the problem. Let $a,b,c \ge1$. Let $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt[3]{x^2 y^2 z^2}(1 - \frac{3 \sqrt[3]{x y z}}{x+y+z})$. Show that $f(ab,bc,ca) \ge f(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the question as
$$
\sqrt[3]{abc} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \ge\!\!? \; \sqrt[3]{abc}  \frac{3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{ab+bc+ca} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \frac{3 \sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}
$$
By AM-GM, both following coefficients are at most $1$:
$$
A =  \frac{3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{ab+bc+ca} \le  1\qquad 
B = \frac{3 \sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\le 1$$
Again, rewrite the question as
$$
\sqrt[3]{abc} - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \ge\!\!? \; \frac{B+A}{2}\Big(\sqrt[3]{abc}  - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \Big) - \frac{B-A}{2}\Big(\sqrt[3]{abc}  + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} \Big) 
$$
So the inequality is immediately proved for the case that
$$
 B =   \frac{3 \sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \ge \frac{3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{ab+bc+ca} = A\\
\leftrightarrow ab + bc + ca \ge (a+b+c)\sqrt[3]{abc}
$$
Now this is not generally true. By symmetry, let w.l.o.g. $c \ge b \ge a$ and realize this by writing $b=a x$ and $c = a x^2 q^3$. Since, by the original question, $a,b,c \ge 1$, we have  $a \ge 1$ and $ x\ge 1$ and $ q^3 x\ge 1$ .  Then we get the equivalent
$$
1 +  x q^3 + x^2 q^3- (1 + x +  x^2 q^3)q \ge 0 \\
\leftrightarrow q^3(1-q)(x-1/q)(x-1/q^2) \ge 0
$$
which is true (since $ x\ge 1$) for
$q \le 1$ and either $x<1/q$ or $x >1/q^2$.

So we need to consider the remaining cases 1.) $q > 1$, and  2.) $q < 1$ and $1/q<x <1/q^2$.

Taking a closer look at case 2.) we can write the condition as $q^2< q^3 x < q$ but,  since also $q <1$ in this case, this never meets the required  $ q^3 x\ge 1$. So case 2.) needs not be considered.

We have case 1.) $q > 1$: Using our substitutions, the original inequality gets

$$
a^2x^2q^2\Big( 1 -  \frac{3xq^2}{1 +  x q^3 + x^2 q^3}  \Big) \ge\!\!? \; 1 -  \frac{3xq}{1 +  x + x^2 q^3} 
$$
Again with $a \ge 1$ and $ x\ge 1$, we can prove the stronger inequality
$$
q^2 -  \frac{3xq^4}{1 +  x q^3 + x^2 q^3}   \ge\!\!? \; 1 -  \frac{3xq}{1 +  x + x^2 q^3} 
$$
Consider first $q$ fixed and $x$ variable. If $x$ increases, the inequality gets less tight. Inspecting  the derivatives w.r.t. $x$, the difference between the LHS and the RHS increases for $x > q^{-3/2}$ and as we have $q>1$ and $x\ge1$, this is always the case. So we only need to consider the tightest case for $x=1$. This leaves us to show
$$
q^2\Big( 1 -  \frac{3q^2}{1 +  2 q^3 }  \Big)  - \Big( 1 -  \frac{3q}{2 +   q^3} \Big)\ge\!\!? \; 0
$$
or
$$
\frac{(q-1)^3(2q^5 + 3q^4 + q^3 + q^2 + 3q + 2)}{(1 +  2 q^3) (2 +   q^3)} \ge\!\!? \; 0 
$$
which is true, since we consider $q>1$.
$\qquad \Box$